An interesting sequence that is convergent.
There is this interesting problem in Peter Walker's Examples and Problems in Analysis:
Let the sequence $x_n$ be defined by $x_1 = 1, x_2 = 2$, and for $n=3,4,\cdots$,
$x_{n+1} = \frac{x_n + x_{n - 1} }{2}$.
Then $x_n$ is a Cauchy sequence.
This is a solved exercise in the book and I am not interested in the solution/proof.
All I'm interested in is the limit of this sequence.

Hint: if $f(x, y)$ is limit of similar sequence starting with $x, y$, then $f(ax + b, ay + b) = a\cdot f(x, y) + b$.

You can try solving the recursion directly. It's easy by the method of characteristic equations, or by some linear algebra.

Seems like $\frac{2}{3}$. Is it so?

@FirdousAhmadMala given that all terms are greater than $1$ - doesn't seem so.

You got the numerator a little wrong. I believe it's $5/3$.

@FirdousAhmadMala, it results that $;x_n=\frac53+\frac43\left(-\frac12\right)^n;,;$ hence $;x_n\to\frac53,.;$

This might be helpful: Linear recurrence with constant coefficients
